# Failure sending mail: Report processing has been canceled by the user. Mail will not be resent

Tags: reporting-services

I'm seeing the error:
"Failure sending mail: Report processing has been canceled by the user. Mail will not be resent."

On a scheduled reporting services report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is rubbish, however on looking at the reporting services logs, which are located:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.SP\Reporting Services\LogFiles

I was able to identify an error was occurring in a custom stored procedure.

On resolving this, the problem was fixed.